# How to convert array of unsigned char to string

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

How do I convert the below `unsigned char` to a `string`:

```
arry<unsigned char>^arrayOne = {0,1,2,3};

textbox1->Text = BitConverter::ToString(arrayOne);
```

I have tried the following

```
unsigned char data[128];

textbox1->Text = BitConverter::ToString(data);
```

Which is failing and producing the following error message:

```
System::BitConverter::ToString
none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why to use unsigned chars instead of regular signed? Otherwise you can always cast and lie to the compiler `gcnew String((char *)data);`

Comment: I get a sample source code and It fixing. I don't know before your coment about 'unsingned'